# C# split XML InnerText

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, parsing, graphml

I have a *.graphml* file which is based on the *XML* data format but allows us to represent graph structures. My problem is that I have many InnerText Elements in one Node and need to split them into an array.

```
...<y:AttributeLabel xml:space="preserve">+Name +Age -Id</y:AttributeLabel>...
```

From this example, I need **+Name**, **+Age** and **-Id** separately stored in an array. 
Can anyone help me out?

Btw the .graphml file is huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string splitOn = @"[\s+-]+";

string[] stringArray= Regex.Split(InnerText, splitOn);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like regex:

```
string[] nameAgeId = InnerText.Split(' ')
                              .Select(x => x.Trim('+', '-')
                              .ToArray();
```